# unsupported node type: param in react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

my expo project is causing an issue only on mobile device, its nothing showing any error on visual studio code command line, my node version is 12.6.1 and expo version is 35.0.0 
[enter image description here][1]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS7si.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with that and I try to change the version of "react-native-reanimated" to the 1.4.0, and that worked for me. I just downgrade to that version.

Answer (score 1):

steps for windows machine:

- Delete .expo and node_modules folder
- run command `npm install react-native-reanimated@1.4.0`
- run command for clear expo cache, `expo r -c`